# Is there a way to plot linear regression in ImageJ?

Tags: java, plot, linear-regression, imagej

I have a coding problem where i want to plot values (x and y) and calculate the linear regression and plot it in imageJ. Can anyone help?

I tried this

```
public class Plot implements PlugIn {
    public void run(String arg) {
        if (IJ.versionLessThan("1.27t"))
            return;

        float[] x = {0.375f, 0.75f, 1.5f, 2.25f, 3f,3.75f,4.5f,4.75f,5f};
        // x-coordinates
        float[] y = {123f,456f,5678f,4567f,4567f,5678f,2345f,4563f,2345f};
        // y-coordinates
        float[] e = {.8f,.6f,.5f,.4f,.3f,.5f,.6f,.7f,.8f};
        // error bars

        PlotWindow plot = new PlotWindow("Example Plot","x-axis","y-axis",x,y);
        plot.setLimits(0, 5.5, 0, 6000);
        plot.addErrorBars(e);

        // add a second curve
        float x2[] = {.4f,.5f,.6f,.7f,.8f};
        float y2[] = {4,3,3,4,5};

        int N=9;
        double sumx = 0.0, sumy = 0.0, sumx2 = 0.0;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            sumx  += x[i];
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            sumx2 += x[i]*x[i];
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            sumy  += y[i];
        double xbar = sumx / N;
        double ybar = sumy / N;

        // second pass: compute summary statistics
        double xxbar = 0.0, yybar = 0.0, xybar = 0.0;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            xxbar += (x[i] - xbar) * (x[i] - xbar);
            yybar += (y[i] - ybar) * (y[i] - ybar);
            xybar += (x[i] - xbar) * (y[i] - ybar);
        }
        slope  = xybar / xxbar;
        intercept = ybar - slope * xbar;

        // more statistical analysis
        double rss = 0.0;      // residual sum of squares
        double ssr = 0.0;      // regression sum of squares
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            double fit = slope*x[i] + intercept; //calculating fit
            rss += (fit - y[i]) * (fit - y[i]);
            ssr += (fit - ybar) * (fit - ybar); //calculating ssr
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What isn't working? How is this code not doing what you expect it to do?

Answer (score 0):

The following [Groovy script](http://imagej.net/Scripting) (which is very similar to Java, and can be run straight from the [Script editor](http://imagej.net/Using_the_Script_Editor) in ImageJ) illustrates how to use the [`ij.gui.Plot`](http://javadoc.imagej.net/ImageJ1/index.html?ij/gui/Plot.html) and [`ij.measure.CurveFitter`](http://javadoc.imagej.net/ImageJ1/index.html?ij/measure/CurveFitter.html) classes to generate a plot with a regression line:

```
import ij.gui.Plot
import ij.measure.CurveFitter

x = [0.375d, 0.75d, 1.5d, 2.25d, 3d,3.75d,4.5d,4.75d,5d];
// x-coordinates
y = [123d,456d,5678d,4567d,4567d,5678d,2345d,4563d,2345d];
// y-coordinates

plot = new Plot("Example Plot","x-axis","y-axis");
plot.addPoints(x,y,Plot.LINE)
plot.setLimits(0, 5.5, 0, 6000);

cf = new CurveFitter((double[]) x, (double[]) y)
cf.doFit(CurveFitter.STRAIGHT_LINE)

yfit = []
for (cx in x) {
    yfit.add(cf.f(cx))
}

plot.addPoints(x, yfit, Plot.LINE)
plotwindow = plot.show()
```

A few recommendations:

- Don't call your own class `Plot`, as a reader of your code might confuse it with `ij.gui.Plot`.
- Use `ij.gui.Plot` instead of `ij.gui.PlotWindow`; the former provides more functionality.
- Don't do a manual regression when there are tools available to do so.
- For questions specific to the [ImageJ and SciJava APIs](http://javadoc.imagej.net/), the best place to ask is the [ImageJ forum](http://forum.imagej.net/).